# Colaboratory VM restarts like clockwork every 45 minutes

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm running Python 2 on a GPU-enabled instance. I am training an LSTM and saving it every 10 cycles. Without fail, the VM restarts every 45 minutes (just before 50 cycles are completed). This has been happening for several days, both on my home wifi (Comcast) and work wifi. I suspect the problem is something native to Google's settings or the Notebook settings, but I can't find anything to tweak this.

My question is: has anyone encountered this? How did you resolve it?

I've included my code here, but I don't think this is code related. It's failing in the last `if epoch % epoch_saving_period ...` block.

```
pickle.dump((seq_length, save_dir), open('params.p', 'wb'))
batches = get_batches(corpus_int, batch_size, seq_length)
num_batches = len(batches)
start_time = time.time()

print "Process started" 

last_checkpoint_prefix = '/tmp/pretrained.ckpt-' + str(last_epoch)

tf.reset_default_graph()

with tf.Session(graph=train_graph) as sess:
    session_config=config
    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
    #tf.add_to_collection('train_op', train_op)
    # If you're loading in a saved model, use the following

    if (last_epoch > 0):
        #saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(last_checkpoint_prefix + '.meta')
        saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('/tmp/'))
        sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    else: 
        # If you're running a fresh session, use the following
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    input_text = train_graph.get_tensor_by_name('input:0')
    initial_state = train_graph.get_tensor_by_name('initial_state:0')
    final_state = train_graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_state:0')
    probs = train_graph.get_tensor_by_name('probs:0')
    targets = train_graph.get_tensor_by_name('targets:0')
    lr = train_graph.get_tensor_by_name('learning_rate:0')

    #init_from_checkpoint('/tmp/pretrained.ckpt', {'input': 'input',
    #                                              'final_state': 'initial_state',
    #                                              'targets': 'targets',
    #                                              'learning_rate': 'learning_rate'})


    epochList = []
    lossList = []
    epoch_saving_period = 10
    epoch = 0

    for epoch in range(last_epoch,(last_epoch+num_epochs)):
        state = sess.run(initial_state, {input_text: batches[0][0]})

        for batch_index, (x, y) in enumerate(batches):
            feed_dict = {
                input_text: x,
                targets: y,
                initial_state: state,
                lr * math.exp(-1 * epoch / 1000): learning_rate
            }
            train_loss, state, _ = sess.run([cost, final_state, train_op], feed_dict)

        time_elapsed = time.time() - start_time
        print('Epoch {:>3} Batch {:>4}/{}   train_loss = {:.3f}   time_elapsed = {:.3f}'.format(
            epoch + 1,
            batch_index + 1,
            len(batches),
            train_loss,
            time_elapsed
            #((num_batches * num_epochs)/((epoch + 1) * (batch_index + 1))) * time_elapsed - time_elapsed),
            ))

        epochList.append(epoch)
        lossList.append(train_loss)

        # save model every 10 epochs
        if epoch % epoch_saving_period == 0:
            last_epoch = epoch - epoch_saving_period 
            #saver = tf.train.Saver()
            #saver.save(sess, save_dir)
            savePath = saver.save(sess, "/tmp/pretrained.ckpt", global_step=epoch, write_meta_graph = True)

            # Copy the file to our new bucket.
            # Full reference: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp
            !gsutil cp /tmp/checkpoint gs://{bucket_name}/
            !gsutil cp /tmp/pretrained.ckpt-{epoch}.index gs://{bucket_name}/
            !gsutil cp /tmp/pretrained.ckpt-{epoch}.meta gs://{bucket_name}/
            !gsutil cp /tmp/pretrained.ckpt-{epoch}.data-00000-of-00001 gs://{bucket_name}/

            !gsutil rm gs://{bucket_name}/pretrained.ckpt-{last_epoch}.index
            !gsutil rm gs://{bucket_name}/pretrained.ckpt-{last_epoch}.meta
            !gsutil rm gs://{bucket_name}/pretrained.ckpt-{last_epoch}.data-00000-of-00001

            print('Model Trained and Saved')

        if epoch % 5 == 0: 
            plt.plot(epochList, lossList)
            plt.title('Train Loss')
            plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you mean every exact 45 mins? Probably your router somehow disconnects from internet at every 45 mins.  I've never been in that situation. When internet is down, CoLab is also down.

Comment: It's not exactly 45 minutes -- maybe a 43 to 45 minute range. It is very reproducible, though. 

I don't think it is the router. I used to be able to run 12 hours on Colaboratory, from both work and home. Now, both locations are limited, and they have different routers / networks / etc. I haven't changed my wifi settings, either.

Comment: Are you running out of memory on the VM?

Comment: Bob, I am not getting an OOM error. I attempted to troubleshoot by inserting a time.sleep() statement into each loop, which caused the connection to persist well beyond 40 minutes. So I think memory may be a root cause. I'll adjust the hyperparameters to use less memory. Thank you!